# Connection timeout for SOCKSProxy Calls in resque Rails production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque, socks

i have simple background job that runs using resque-pool which makes certain socksproxy call. This works fine  when i start the resque-pool in Rails development mode as soon as i change to production mode i hit connection timeout with background job

The same code works when executed in

- Rails Console in Production mode
- Standalone ruby script invoked from command line

calls are something like:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy(@socks_server, @socks_port).start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
    http.request(req)
end
```

Investigation:

when this call happens in `net/http.rb`

```
TCPSocket.open(conn_address, conn_port, @local_host, @local_port)
```

i found that in production mode worker child process instead of loading
`TCPSocket` class from `socksify-1.7.0/lib/socksify.rb` it is still loading from ruby provided `resolv-replace.rb`. Not sure why though.

Error i see:

> Connection timed out - connect(2) for "" port 6455:
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/socksify-1.7.0/lib/socksify.rb:178:in
>   `initialize'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/socksify-1.7.0/lib/socksify.rb:178:in`
>   initialize' /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv-replace.rb:23:in `initialize'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in`open'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in`timeout'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in`do_start'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:583:in`start' 
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/retries-0.0.5/lib/retries.rb:46:in
>   `call' 
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/retries-0.0.5/lib/retries.rb:46:in`
>   with_retries' 
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.26.0/lib/resque/job.rb:177:in
>   `block (3 levels) in perform' 
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.16.2.321/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/resque.rb:41:in`
>   block in around_perform_with_monitoring' 
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.16.2.321/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:363:in
>   `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
>
> > /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.16.2.321/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/resque.rb:33:in
> >     `around_perform_with_monitoring' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.26.0/lib/resque/job.rb:176:in`
> >     block (2 levels) in perform' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.26.0/lib/resque/job.rb:172:in
> >     `call' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.26.0/lib/resque/job.rb:172:in`
> >     block (3 levels) in perform'  ../app/jobs/resque_hooks.rb:15:in
> >     `around_perform_job_duration' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.26.0/lib/resque/job.rb:172:in`
> >     block (2 levels) in perform' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.26.0/lib/resque/job.rb:184:in
> >     `call' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.26.0/lib/resque/job.rb:184:in`
> >     perform' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.26.0/lib/resque/worker.rb:290:in
> >     `perform' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.26.0/lib/resque/worker.rb:229:in`
> >     block in work' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.26.0/lib/resque/worker.rb:206:in
> >     `loop' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.26.0/lib/resque/worker.rb:206:in`
> >     work' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-pool-0.6.0/lib/resque/pool.rb:396:in
> >     `block in spawn_worker!' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-pool-0.6.0/lib/resque/pool.rb:389:in`
> >     fork' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-pool-0.6.0/lib/resque/pool.rb:389:in
> >     `spawn_worker!' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-pool-0.6.0/lib/resque/pool.rb:367:in`
> >     block in spawn_missing_workers_for' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-pool-0.6.0/lib/resque/pool.rb:366:in
> >     `times' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-pool-0.6.0/lib/resque/pool.rb:366:in`
> >     spawn_missing_workers_for' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-pool-0.6.0/lib/resque/pool.rb:352:in
> >     `block in maintain_worker_count' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-pool-0.6.0/lib/resque/pool.rb:350:in`
> >     each' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-pool-0.6.0/lib/resque/pool.rb:350:in
> >     `maintain_worker_count' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-pool-0.6.0/lib/resque/pool.rb:263:in`
> >     start' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-pool-0.6.0/lib/resque/pool.rb:89:in
> >     `run' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/resque-pool-0.6.0/lib/resque/pool/tasks.rb:17:in`
> >     block (2 levels) in ' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in
> >     `call' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in`
> >     block in execute' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in
> >     `each' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in`
> >     execute' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/airbrake-5.5.0/lib/airbrake/rake/task_ext.rb:19:in
> >     `execute' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in`
> >     block in invoke_with_call_chain' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize' 
> >     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in`
> >     invoke_with_call_chain

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation it turns due to newrelic gem enabled in production mode. newrelic requires `resolv-replace` this didnt go well with socksify gem and resque background job. As i did not need new relic anymore, simply by disabling it i was able to overcome this issue.